# Can you attach hook scripts to be run on Windows login and logoff events?

Tags: windows

If you wanted to copy files to / from a directory on Windows login / logoff, could you use the event viewer to run a hook script that copies them from / to a directory when the logon / logoff events are fired by a user logging on / logging off?

Comment: Yes;  You can run a script when a user logs into and out of their account

Comment: Can you specify just one user that kicks off the hook?  Not all of them?

Comment: The event will happen to all users, but within the script, you can check for which user it is.

Comment: What is doing this refered to as?

Comment: What do you mean?  You want to configure a scheduled task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will sample how to copy a file from SMB network share `10.10.10.10\Share\file1.txt` to the local `C:\users\user2\desktop\file1.txt`

First, we need to make a script to actually copy the files.

Open a new notepad document.
Paste in the following:

`copy \\10.10.10.10\Share\file1.txt c:\users\user1\desktop\file1.txt`

Save it as `copyFileScript.bat`

Now, login to the user that needs the script ran on login.

- Click the start button and type task scheduler and open it.
- On the far right, choose Create Task. Do not choose basic task.
- There will be 5 tabs here, General, Triggers, Actions, Conditions and
  Settings.

**General Tab:**

- Name: Turn off Network Access
- Choose "Run only when user is logged on"
- Tick the box for "Run with highest privileges"

**Triggers Tab:**

- Click "New"
- Begin the task dropdown: "At Logon"
- Press OK

**Actions Tab:**

- Click "New"
- Action: Start a program
- Browse for program/script and choose your newly created .bat
- Click OK

**Conditions Tab:**

- Uncheck: "Start the task only if AC is on"
- Uncheck: "Stop if computer switches to battery"
- Click OK

**Settings Tab:**

- No changes.

Press OK. You may now be prompted with a credential asking for admin credentials. If this is the case, enter the username/password of an account on the computer that is an administrator. Depending where you are copying the files from, you may not need admin rights. You can test that. Logout and log back in to the user that has the script configured and the batch should run to copy the files.